# Laravel Many to many relationship pivot not wowrking

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5

I have 3 tables

`User: user_serno(primary key), username, email`

`Role: role_serno(primary key), name`

`User_role_pivot: user_role_privot_serno(primary key), user_serno(foreign key), role_serno(foreign key)`

And I have a belongsToMany in my UserModel

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\RoleModel', 
        'USER_ROLE_PIVOT', 
        'ROLE_SERNO', 
        'ROLE_SERNO');
```

I am trying to fetch a user with roles and I keep getting empty result, checked query it's not correct.

`$user = UserModel::find(121)->roles;`

I can fetch the user, but roles isn't working, below are the queries executed:

First:
`select t2.* from ( select rownum AS "rn", t1.* from (select * from USER where USER.USER_SERNO = '121') t1 ) t2 where t2."rn" between 1 and 1`

Second:
`select ROLE.*, USER_ROLE_PIVOT.ROLE_SERNO as pivot_ROLE_SERNO from ROLE inner join USER_ROLE_PIVOT on ROLE.ROLE_SERNO = USER_ROLE_PIVOT.ROLE_SERNO where USER_ROLE_PIVOT.ROLE_SERNO is null`

Why does it have ROLE_SERNO is null ! I think it should be USER_SERNO = 121

Answer (score 0):

The belongToMany function in your UserModel should be defined like this :

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\RoleModel', 
        'User_role_pivot', 
        'user_serno',
        'role_serno');
```

For mentioning the associated keys, first mention the current model's(UserModel) key and then the other model's(RoleModel) key. You are using same key in both.